# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `app` supplied to `Body`, expected a single ReactElement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm trying to pass my `App` component to my `Body` component. It works and it seems to render fine, but I'm getting the above warning in my console. Here is my code:

**Document.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from './Head';
import Body from './Body';
import App from '../timer/App';

const Document = () => (
  <html>
    <Head />
    <Body app={App} />
  </html>
);

export default Document;
```

**Body.js**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const Body = ({ app: App }) => (
  <body>
    <App />
    <script src='/js/bundle.js'></script>
  </body>
);

Body.propTypes = {
  app: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};

export default Body;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => (
  <h1>Hello</h1>
);

export default App;
```

There are no other errors, and the `App` is rendering fine, so I'm not sure why the `propType` is failing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason why you're passing your App as an attribute rather than a child? You could do this: `<Body><App /></Body>` then in your Body.js, switch `<App/>` with `{this.props.children}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Body app={App} />
```

`App` is not a React Element yet, its a function(`PropTypes.func`) which is used to create the App Element.

This is what you are passing right now

```
<Body app={function App() {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement(
      'h1',
      null,
      'Hello'
    )
  );
}} />
```

If you want to pass a React Element, you should use `<App/>` instead of `App`

```
<Body app={<App/>} />
```

which is like

```
<Body app={React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        React.createElement(
          'h1',
          null,
          'Hello'
        )
)} />
```

so you'll be able to render it like this

```
const Body = ({ app }) => {
   return <body>
       {app}
       <script src='/js/bundle.js'></script>
       </body>
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49384/)